# Xcode > Product > Archive, codesign issue

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode

When I choose Product > Archive in xcode, I got this message:

"codesign wants to sign using key "< key >" in your keychain."

[image]

I think there is something wrong, it should not show "< key >" , right??

Thanks!!

Comment: What happens once you allow that access?

Comment: Just use "Always Allow". It actually allows developer certificate to be accessed by Xcode

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just select Always allow. There is no issue using it. It actually make available the developer certificate to the XCode app. So that using it Xcode can sign your application. Once you select Always allow. It should not ask you again in future.

Comment: I did see this message before, but it was showing my name instead of "< key >", so I wonder anything go wrong as this is my first time submitting app to app store.

Comment: Its No issue anyways. BTW Just check your login keychain for the developer certificate installation.